# SQL Server Fetch Slow until after a ClearCache

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, fetch

A user is experiencing very slow performance.  I can see duration of a fetch statement that aligns to the performance time.  There is no blocking or deadlocks and no waits that are unreasonable.

After I do a clear cache on the database the user immediately sees response time improve from a minute to several seconds.  I see that a fetch statement no longer is at a high level but appears after a time at several seconds.

Does this recompilation change something about how the fetch is done or is it something about what is being done within the loop within the fetch processing.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot see the cursor definition I have to assume that it is not a STATIC cursor otherwise the clearing of the cache would have had no impact on response time since the recompile of the cursor would have had no impact because all of the fetched data would already have been in the temp table.

If the cursor were any of the others KEYSET, DYNAMIC (default) or FAST-FORWARD (unless it chose STATIC), the recompile of the fetch could possibly have had an impact on the execution plan.

That would explain the difference between the response time.